# Prove $f([0,1])\in [0,1]^2$ for space-filling curve

Tags: real-analysis

I am working on the construction of Hilbert's space-filling curve. I have showed that there exists a continuous function $$f_n:[0,1]\to [0,1]^2$$ such that all points in $[0,1]^2$ are within $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2^{n+1}}$ of some point $f_n(t)$ and if $m\geq n$ then $$|f_m(t)-f_n(t)|\leq \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2^{n+1}}.$$ I have then showed $f_n(t)$ converge to a continuous function $$f:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}^2.$$ I want to show that the image of $f$ is in fact contained in $[0,1]^2$. It is intuitive, since the image of $f_n$ is contained in $Q$ and $f_n$ can be chosen close enough to $f$, but I struggle to prove it.

Comment: It is obvious: $f(t)=\lim_{n\to \infty} f_n(t)$ and $f_n(t)\in [0,1]^2$ for all $n$, so the same is true for its limit.

Answer (score 1):

The set $[0, 1]^2 \subset \mathbb R$ is closed, so it therefore contains all its own limit points.